# FlatList: What are the properties of ListRenderItemInfo<>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to use a FlatList like this:

```
          <FlatList
          data={vehicles}
          horizontal={false}
          scrollEnabled
          renderItem={({ vehicle}) => <VehicleContainer vehicle={vehicle} />}
          keyExtractor={(vehicle: any) => vehicle.numberPlate.toString()}
        />
```

where `vehicles`looks like this:

```
[{numberPlate: "OL-AL-1336", __typename: "Vehicle"}]
```

and the component `VehicleContainer`looks like this:

```
type VehicleContainerProps = {
  vehicle: Vehicle;
};

export const VehicleContainer: React.FunctionComponent<VehicleContainerProps> = ({
  vehicle,
}) => {
  if (!vehicle) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.vehicleInfo}>
          <Text style={styles.numberPlate}>{vehicle.numberPlate}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

But I keep getting an error on renderItem's vehicle that `Property 'vehicle' does not exist on type 'ListRenderItemInfo<Vehicle>'`What is `ListRenderItemInfo`? It's not something I have defined myself. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

renderItem takes object as argument and that object contains:

{ item, index, separators }

which means in your code you cannot destruct vehicle from it, but instead your vehicle is represented as item.

so you have to write it like this:

```
renderItem={({item}) => <VehicleContainer vehicle={item} />}
```